# .Net Core Data Annotation clarification

Tags: asp.net-core

Can someone please guide which one of the below is the correct Data Annotation, if I want to allow just alphabets:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
```

OR

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
```

Both seems to be working. The difference is `^` symbol.

Comment: are you sure they both work? non-alphabets should pass the validation as well because you use `*` which is optional. The correct pattern should be `^[a-zA-Z]+` (requiring at least one char). Usually if the whole value should be matched, you can use the `$` at the end and then you can use `*` as an optional matching, like this `^[a-zA-Z]*$` (allowing empty strings).

Comment: Should a string like "Test1" be matched or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` Caret is a ***Position Anchor***.

Position Anchors does not match character, but position such as start-of-line, end-of-line, start-of-word and end-of-word.

In this case you need both `^` and `$`: start-of-line and end-of-line respectively. E.g., `^[0-9]$` matches a numeric string.

So you should go with,

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
```

Becase you need strings starts and ends with alphabetical characters only, not having any other characters such as symbols or numerals. Here are some examples that you can play with.

```js
let str1 = 'abcDef';
let str2 = '123abcDef';
let str3 = 'abcDef123';
let str4 = 'abc123Def';

let my_regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
let your_regex = /[a-zA-Z]*/;

alert(str1 + " : " + my_regex.test(str1) + " with my regex");
alert(str2 + " : " + my_regex.test(str2) + " with my regex");
alert(str3 + " : " + my_regex.test(str3) + " with my regex");
alert(str4 + " : " + my_regex.test(str4) + " with my regex");

alert(str1 + " : " + your_regex.test(str1) + " with your regex");
alert(str2 + " : " + your_regex.test(str2) + " with your regex");
alert(str3 + " : " + your_regex.test(str3) + " with your regex");
alert(str4 + " : " + your_regex.test(str4) + " with your regex");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
```

which says to match

1. the beginning of the string `^`
2. followed by 1 or more alphabetic characters `[a-zA-Z]+` (you do need more than zero right)?
3. followed by the end of the string `$`

This doesn't allow other strings to match such as `123abc` or `abc123` because the anchors of `^` and `$` prevent that.

In your first example, the match would allow an empty string, and would allow for the cases I mentioned in the paragraph above. Your second example would allow empty string, but would at least filter out `123abc` but would still allow `abc123` because you don't have the `$` marker.

If you want to take my solution and extend it beyond ASCII alphabetic characters, you can change `[a-ZA-Z]+` to `\p{L}+`, which should work universally in Unicode (but that seems like it might be more than you're looking for; just including for completeness).

Finally, `[RegularExpression]` uses the standard regex capability that has been part of .NET for quite some time, expressed in the [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The Caret (^) character is also referred to by the following terms:

**Terminology**
hat, control, uparrow, chevron, circumflex accent

**Usage**

It has two uses in regular expressions:

To denote the start of the line
If used immediately after a square bracket `([^)` it acts to negate the set of allowed characters (i.e. [123] means the character 1, 2, or 3 is allowed, whilst the statement `[^123]` means any character other than 1, 2, or 3 is allowed.
Character Escaping

To express a caret without special meaning, it should be escaped by preceding it with a backslash; i.e. ^.

[You can find it here...](https://sodocumentation.net/regex/topic/452/anchor-characters--caret----)